# Trouble using java connectivity and data transmition on libgdx

Tags: javascript

Hello everybody i have a trouble making datatransmition with mine program just to give the idea im trying to move this blocks when i move mine cars

[image]

Here I leave the encoding of mine server/client program

```
package com.mygdx.Xrace;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

import java.net.Socket;

public class ScreenServidor extends Pantallabase{

        ScreenCarrera carrera;
        MyTextInputListener listener;
        ServerSocket server ;
        float delta = 0.01f;
        int puerto=9600;
        public ScreenServidor(Main game) {
            super(game);
        }
        @Override       
        public void show()
        {
            carrera=new ScreenCarrera(game);
            carrera.show();

            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(puerto);
                new User(server.accept()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println(e);
                }finally{
                        try {
                            server.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                             System.out.println(e);
                        }
                }

        }   


        @Override
        public void render(float delta)
        {
            carrera.render(delta);
        }
        @Override
        public void dispose(){
            carrera.dispose();
            }
        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height) {}
        @Override
        public void pause() {}
        @Override
        public void resume() {}
        @Override
        public void hide() {
        }
}
class User extends Thread{

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    Socket conexion;
    ScreenCarrera carrera;
    public User(Socket serv)
    {
        this.conexion=serv;
    }
    public void run() {

        try {

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexion.getInputStream())); 
            out=new PrintWriter(conexion.getOutputStream(),true);
            **carrera.m.posx2=in.read();** //receiving data
            **out.print(carrera.m.posx1);**//sending data
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println(e);
        }finally{
            try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            conexion.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    }

}

package com.mygdx.Xrace;

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class ScreenCliente extends Pantallabase{

    Socket conexion;
    ScreenCarrera carrera;
    PrintStream out ;
    MyTextInputListener listener;
    BufferedReader in;
    float delta = 0.01f;
    int puerto=9600;

    static String ip;

    public ScreenCliente(Main game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        carrera=new ScreenCarrera(game);
        carrera.show();
        conexion=new Socket();
        listener = new MyTextInputListener();
        Gdx.input.getTextInput(listener, "ingrese ip", ip, ip);
        try {

            conexion =new Socket(ip,puerto);
            out = new PrintStream(conexion.getOutputStream(),true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexion.getInputStream()));

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        carrera.render(delta);
        try{
        **carrera.m.posx2=in.read()**;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            game.m.mensaje="error de conexion";
            game.setScreen(game.m);
        }try {
            run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void run() throws IOException{

         **out.print(carrera.m.posx1);**
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }
    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }
    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        carrera.dispose();
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            conexion.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question looks like it would belong to StackOverflow rather than here.